# Multiple application context. How to get context per key?

Tags: java, spring, cdi, applicationcontext

I have few problems during upgrade Spring version in application.

In legacy code we are using BeanFactoryLocator in order to get main context (registry) in which defined all other contexts. After I am getting BeanFactoryReference by name.

```
BeanFactoryLocator beanFactoryLocator = DefaultLocatorFactory.getInstance(k.getSelector() // name of the main context, kind of registry for other contexts);
            BeanFactoryReference factoryRef = beanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(k.getFactoryName() // name of the concrete context xml);
            BeanFactory factory = new FactoryWrapper(factoryRef.getFactory(), k.getFactoryName());
return factory;
```

In Spring 5.0 there is no BeanFactoryLocator, DefaultLocatorFactory objects. How I can implement it another way?

Comment: http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/04/using-spring-contextsingletonbeanfactor.html#.Wo0uO66WYkI - I have something similar to this. 

Please advice how I can implement it in Spring 5.x

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting discussion [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15154) about the outdated mechanism of using beanFactoryLocator, Juergen Hoeller recommended to use

> a custom static holder class for one or more ApplicationContexts,
>   keyed by something that has a meaning for your use case, and with a
>   proper lifecycle.